# Calculating all bitonic paths

Tags: algorithm, traveling-salesman

I'm trying to calculate all bitonic paths for a given set of points.

Given N points.

My guess is there are O(n!) possible paths.

Reasoning

You have n points you can choose from your starting location. From there you have n-1 points, then n-2 points...which seems to equal n!.

Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: What makes you think it is O(n!) ? As far as I can see there are two options for each point: be on the upper path or lower path. Of course the decisions are not independent for each point. So there can be at most 2^n paths.

Comment: Do you mean [bitonic tours](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitonic_tour)? I believe not every hamiltonian path in a graph forms a bitonic tour, thus the number of these tours is strictly smaller then number of paths.

Comment: are you looking for number of maximal bitonic tours? If you looking for bitonic tour which is also hamiltonian, sure some (complete)graphs doesn't have such a bitonic tour.

Comment: If you only care about an algorithmic answer, I think this question is better for http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it with good old dynamic programming.

Let Count(top,bottom) be the number of incomplete tours such that top is the rightmost top row point and bottom is the rightmost point and all the points left of top are bottom are already in the trail.

Now, Count(i,j) = Count(k,j) where k={i-1}U{l: l

This is O(n^3) complexity.

If you want to enumerate all the bitonic trails, along with Count also keep track of all the paths. In the update step append path appropriately. This would require a lot of memory though. If you don't want to use lot of memory use recursion (same idea. sort the points. At every recursion point either put the new point is top fork or the bottom fork and check if there are any crossings)

Comment: How does this give you *all* bitonic paths?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft If you want to print all the paths, you need to store all the temporary paths until each point.

Comment: I don't know why you got two upvotes? enumeration and counting are two different problems, sometimes there is no need to enumerate to find out count of something, and seems OP looks for enumeration. (As he mentioned by his O(n!) guess). Also I can't see how you are going to enumerate paths with your Count method?

Comment: @SaeedAmiri See the last paragraph about enumerating. Keep a list of *ALL* partial paths.

Comment: I see that but I couldn't get how you do it?

Comment: @SaeedAmiri Let me put it abstractly. If F(x) = F(x1) + F(x2) be dynamic programming step, each of these F(x1) and F(x2) have list of solutions, L1 and L2, associated with them. For each solutions in L1 concatenate x1->x, and similarly L2. Take the union of these two sets.  L = {concat(i,x1->x): for i in L1) \Union {concat(i,x2->x): for i in L2). Note that |L1|=F(x1), |L2|=F(x2) and |L|=F(x).